# Accessibility error Duplicate labels used

Tags: html, accessibility

I have form

```
<form onsubmit="return false;" class="city-form-inner">
          <div id="ember506" class="wrap-autocomplete ember-view">  <label for="search-locations-address">Enter ZIP, State or City</label>
    <div class="autocomplete-input">
      <input aria-label="Enter ZIP, State or City" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" type="text" name="search-locations-address" id="search-locations-address" class="form-control ember-text-field ember-view ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off">
    <ul id="ui-id-1" tabindex="0" class="ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-autocomplete custom-autocomplete ui-front" role="listbox" style="display: none;"></ul></div>
    <div role="status" aria-live="polite" class="autocomplete-status">0 results are available, use up and down arrow keys to navigate</div>
    </div>
          <input type="button" value="Find Stores" class="btn-blue submit" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-513="513">
        </form>
```

and have same form in modal window, after run ARC toolkit test I get error about duplicate labels, I tried `aria-hidden` `aria-disabled` for form not in modal but it didn't help^`aria-labelledby` for input and nothing help or started saying the wrong text, can please hint me?

Comment: Could it be because of you using the same id `search-locations-address` in 2 forms ? Does it help if you assign unique ids to inputs in each form ?

Comment: WCAG guidance on form labels: https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/forms/labels/. Ids are unique and should not repeat.

Answer (score 2):

It might be because your `<input>` has two labels, a `<label>` element and an `aria-label`, and they happen to have the same text.  I'm not sure if that triggers the warning but it's a concern in the code.  The `<label>` will be ignored because `aria-label` takes precedence as noted in the [Accessible Name Computation](https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.1/#step2) (step 2C is about `aria-label` and 2D is about `<label>`).

```
<label for="search-locations-address">Enter ZIP, State or City</label>
...
<input aria-label="Enter ZIP, State or City" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" type="text" name="search-locations-address" id="search-locations-address" class="form-control ember-text-field ember-view ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off">
```

It doesn't hurt anything in this case but is extra code you don't need.  You should remove the `aria-label` from the `<input>`.

Comment: Yep don't use aria if the proper html element is in place, in this case the label needs to be connected to the field using label for="", and don't need an aria label on the input because it's described by its label https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/forms/labels/

Comment: The original code already had the `for` attribute on the `<label>` element

Comment: In your answer, the input is described by the label for so the input doesn't need the aria label. In fact having both can confuse screenreaders into not reading anything as a result.

Comment: The code in my answer was a copy of the original code. I wanted to show the two lines that showed the two labels. Having both will not confuse the screen reader because it’s going to use the accessible name computation, https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.1/#terminology

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand the intent. Actually having multiple has failed in tests I've done personally so it happens.